# Unstructured data storage .net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webapplication and some configuration files like resx and metadata.xml are stored on file system. Technically a folder under IIS because the web application is a .net 4.6 application. With this approach the web application cannot be scaled. I am just trying to see if there is a common place to store this other than Distributed File System? How to solve the Single point of failure ?

Comment: Why can't it be scaled? two web servers = 2 copies of the file

Comment: Yes but these files are updated from within the application. Like someone add a resource label in the application the resx files get updated. So now the changes won't reach the second server automatically..

Comment: Then you probably need to improve your deployment process

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: That really depends on how you are doing it now. How do you deploy? Just right click deploy in VS? There are a bunch of tools (which I know nothing about, including those in TFS that assist with deployment. If you are at the stage where you need to consider scaling out then you also need to consider using a deployment tool

Comment: Not sure if this is really a deployment issue. As these files are updated as part of the web application. If you have a cluster of IIS servers how will the changes made in one site reflected in all sites. If the files are stored on file system.

Comment: Well perhaps its configuration instead. Regardless, there are processes to follow for application deployment or configuration. These processes might be manual or they might be automated. How do you deploy these files now? Manually copy them on? That manual process can be extended to copy on to all servers.... if I understand correctly

Comment: The files are first installed using MSI/exe. After the application is installed. User can login to the application and change the label inside the application. When change to the label is updated to the resx file but it goes only to one app server. But the same change need to be synced to other server to reflect the label change.

Comment: "change the label inside the application". So the files in question are changed by the application, it's not source code and it's not configuration. You could always just store these files on some kind of shared folder that multiple IIS servers can see. I don't have any 'best practice enterprise patterns' for you, but there is a multitude of ways to solve this.